# How to show custom image progress in Android?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I want to show a progress bar like below. 
https://www.uplabs.com/posts/freebie-preloade03

How to do that and which image format will work? Please give your inputs.

Comment: easy way will be take a gif and show it in loop.

Comment: how about using lottie animations google it

Answer (score 0):

Okay there is a lot of tricks you can do but the easiest one will be onLoad fetch the data and in layout, everything you have is set Display to none, and on Data fetched you just set them visible again. Or just use the ConstraintLayout over LinearLayout with LL set to null till the data is being fetched.